# Use jquery onlick to insert an element value into a form

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to use jquery to have elements' (in this case images) values entered into a hidden form when they are clicked on (and in the green div) But when they get clicked again the value removed from the form input (when the element is in the blue div). How can I do this, with an unlimited (dynamic) number of element values that need to go into the form?
For the sake of the example, the form field is visible to see if the values get entered.

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfZX/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bottom-div").on("click","img",function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#top-div");
    });
    $("#top-div").on("click","img",function(){
        $(this).appendTo("#bottom-div");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the elements of the target-div when the form is submitted and pass them as a JSON array in the form like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    //create an array
    values = [];
    //add all images in #top-div to the array
    $('#top-div img').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).attr('src'));
    });
    //set the JSON stringified array as the inputs value
    $('input[type=text]').val(JSON.stringify(values));
});​
```

Comment: How would I break down the array with my php?

Comment: `foreach( json_decode( $_POST['input_name'] ) as $item ){
  echo $item;
}`